# Python 3 dictionary.get() function not working with sys.stdin

Tags: python, dictionary, get

I am currently writing a dictionary program that allows the user to enter in two words: an English word and its foreign translation. Then, the user should be able to input a foreign word and retrieve the English word; however, I am required to use sys.stdin for the second half.

```
import sys

dictionary = dict()
userInput = input()
while userInput != "":
    buf = userInput.split()
    english = buf[0]
    foreign = buf[1]
    dictionary[foreign] = english
    userInput = input()

for userInput in sys.stdin:
    print(type(userInput))
    if userInput in dictionary:
        print(dictionary.get(userInput))
    else:
        print("Word not in dictionary.")
```

When I use sys.stdin, the dictionary.get() function is not functioning properly. When I simply use the normal input() function instead of sys.stdin, the dictionary is able to function properly. Why is this and how can I get sys.stdin to properly work with the dictionary search?

This code seems to work, but once again... it used input() instead of sys.stdin:

```
import sys

dictionary = dict()
userInput = input()
while userInput != "":
    buf = userInput.split()

    english = buf[0]
    foreign = buf[1]

    dictionary[foreign] = english
    userInput = input()

userInput = input()
while userInput != "":
    if userInput in dictionary:
        print(dictionary.get(userInput))
    else:
        print("Word not in dictionary")

    userInput = input()
```

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried `print(userInput)`? or better yet, `print(repr(userInput))`? I suspect there is trailing whitespace you aren't handling correctly.

Comment: There is a trailing `\n`.

Comment: How can I handle the trailing \n?

Comment: `text = text.rstrip('\n')` to remove all `\n` on the right side. Or if you always get text with `\n` at the end `text = text[:-1]`

Comment: Note that the `.get` method already lets you specify a default value if the key you supplied is not in the dictionary.  So, for you case, you can use `print(dictionary.get(userInput, "Word not in dictionary"))` instead of your `if ... else ...` block.

Comment: Thanks everyone! Got it to work; the newline was the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A trailing '\n' was the issue. `string = string.rstrip('\n')` fixed this for me.